# Creating Forms in Qt creator IDE

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer

For many projects (like [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-quick-start.html)) I need to create a *Form* using the Qt creator IDE and then work on that *Form*.
I use the Qt creator 3.6.0 which is the latest Qt IDE.
There I have `File -> New File or Project` and the `templates` are just like the page below:
http://www.4shared.com/download/AM4KhauNba/Capture__2_.PNG?sbsr=7242

But the tutorial says that I need to create a *Form* (!) and sometimes, using one of the `MainWindow` templates. But I have only `All Templates` and `Desktop Templates` (top-right corner of the screenshot).

If I cannot create that Form, I then will not be able to do the tutorial's instructions.
This may be the problem of any other beginner of Qt, that uses the new Qt creator IDE.
Would anybody help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the answer. I hope this helps other new beginners as well. :-)

I should select from the menu: *File > New File or Project* ...
This will produce a dialog like this one:

[image: form]

I must choose `Qt` and `Qt Designer Form`, click on the `Choose` ... button and then follow the wizard.